# How to solve a min max problem?

Tags: nonconvex-programming, heuristics, bilevel-optimization

The optimization model is defined as,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_{\bf x}\max_{\bf y}f_{0}(y)\\
s.t.\bf f_1(y)=0\\
\bf f_2(y)\leq0\\
\bf f_{3}(x,y)\leq0\\
\bf f_{4}(x)\leq0
\end{aligned}
$$
where $f_0(y)$ is nonconvex with bilinear terms. $\bf f_1(y)$ are linear equalities.  $\bf f_2(y)$ are second order cone constraints.  $\bf f_3(x,y)$ are linear inequalities.  $\bf f_4(x)$ are nonconvex inequalities (including indicator function).

How can I solve this problem using heuristic algorithms?

Comment: This could be entered in Gurobi or BARON, among other possible global optimization solvers. How to enter the problem depends on what modeling or solver interface is used. If the problem is not  of small dimension, it might not be easy computationally to solve to a small optimality gap.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone
Are there any algorithms or links that I can learn from? Apart from calling the solvers, I also want to write a code to implement it.

Comment: Do you want to solve a problem, or do you want to develop an algorithm/software for its own sake? If the former, I recommend you start with my suggestions and see how they go. if the latter, I'll let someone else answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to solve it with a tailored heuristic?, or is using a metaheuristic fine? For the second, you could check these links:

- A systematic review of metaheuristics: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11831-023-10030-1
- Lectures for Metaheuristics optimization: https://iao.hfuu.edu.cn/teaching/lectures/metaheuristic-optimization
- Constraint handling techniques for metaheuristics: a state-of-the-art review and new variants: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11081-022-09782-9

If you want to code them in Python, check this: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/optimization-modelling-in-python-metaheuristics-with-constraints-c22b08c487e8

If you are using Julia, check this package: https://jmejia8.github.io/Metaheuristics.jl/stable/